# block multiple instances of firefox app

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, tabs

I have built a Firefox 22 application in JavaScript/HTML5 and I would like to block the user from opening multiple instances of it (whether it be in a separate tab or a separate browser).

Currently this works to the extent that when you try to open another instance of it, it redirects to about:blank, brings the original instance of the application into focus (switches tab or window), and displays an alert (on the original instance). This is done checking a displayState variable I've set in localStorage.

The problem I've run into is that while the alert is up, the user can open as many instances of the application as he/she wants.

Is there a better way than using (a displayState check in) localStorage to do this? Or is there a way to keep the alert from timing-out the application?

Comment: Could you use a pop-up/dialog instead of an alert?

Answer (score 1):

Alert blocks script execution in Firefox (this is not so for e.g. Opera), you hardly can change this. Therefore you should use something different.

Nonetheless you may set `localStorage` key on application startup and unset it on shutdown (`window.onunload`). User can get stuck, though, if browser crashes.
You may try `SessionStorage`, which is automatically cleaned when browser is closed.